# Looking up domain name availability using javascript

Tags: javascript, dns

I'm working on a name generator site - which provides suggestions for domain / business names.

I'd like to add in the ability to check if the domain names it generates are already taken or available.

Is there a way to do this on the client side (using javascript) rather than on the backend/server side?

Comment: Using `fetch`?  Anything else special about your call?

Comment: Wouldn't that run into cross domain / XSS issues if fetch is used for a different domain?

Answer (score 1):

I just googled "check domain name available" and found this site, first result:

https://www.name.com/domain/search/test

The "test" in the end is your search-term.

I'd just append the domain-name you want at the end of "https://www.name.com/domain/search/" and then use the [fetch method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to see if it's available.

You could search for a string like "test.com is not available." - because that's what you would get back from your fetch call.

Maybe not the most elegant way to solve it, but it works.

Comment: Wouldn't this run into cross domain / XSS restrictions as its making a request to a different domain?